# Broken packages and unmet dependencies while installing wine

Tags: dependencies

So, I'm having problems installing wine in ubuntu. I did exactly what it had to be done to install wine via terminal and once typed in the line

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-staging
```

it outputs this

```
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libswresample2 : Depends: libsoxr0 (>= 0.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
 winehq-staging : Depends: wine-staging (= 3.7.0~trusty)
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I've already looked it up on the internet and tried any solution they gave users, this includes

```
sudo apt.get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install -f
```

I've also tried to check the repositories in the software&updates. I'm running on a 64bit.
also tried

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
```

I also removed every wine package before installing it but still nothing. Tried to reinstall it but still nothing happens it always give me the same error. 
so i tried to install libswresample2 but it said it was already at it's newest version. 
Is there anyway to fix this?
I'm a bit of a newbie in ubuntu so be patient with me thanks.

Comment: do you need wine-staging for some reason? what happens if you install wine-stable?

Comment: no but it's giving me the same problem while installing the stable version just not giving me the libswresample2 problem: 'The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 3.0.0~trusty)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
'

Comment: I've also tried with aptitude instead of apt-get and when I run it with '--with-recommends' it just outputs that no packages are going to be installed, updated or upgraded